# How to make collapsing header in react native – circular dependency in animation

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm trying to build a collapsing header above a FlatList, the way eg. search bars in email apps work. When you scroll down, it should collapse the header, and when you scroll up, the header should appear again. My code looks something like this

```
const onScroll = event => {
    //console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset);
    Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollOffsetY } } }], {
      useNativeDriver: false,
    })(event);
  };

  const HEADER_HEIGHT = 113;
  const scrollOffsetY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const scrollOffsetClamped = scrollOffsetY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
  });
  const translateY = Animated.multiply(
    Animated.diffClamp(scrollOffsetClamped, 0, HEADER_HEIGHT),
    -1,
  );

...

<Animated.View
  style={{
    opacity: headerOpacity,
    transform: [{ translateY: translateY }],
  }}
>
  {Header content that should disappear on scroll-down}
</Animated.View>

<Animated.View
  style={{ transform: [{ translateY: translateY }], height: '100%' }}
>
  <View>
    {A piece of the header that should always be visible}
  </View>
  <FlatList
   onScroll={event => onScroll(event)}
  />
</Animated.View>
```

My problem is what seems to be a circular dependency between the scroll offset and `translateY`. When scrolling up, the scroll offset decreases, and so the `diffClamp` in the definition of `translateY` decreases, bringing the header into view. However, this means the FlatList's visible area decreases (by design, the whole point of the collapsing header is to provide more real estate for the list). But it seems to me that when the FlatList's visible window shrinks, the scrollOffset increases, since the offset needs to be larger to have the items in the same position with a smaller window, and since the scroll offset is now larger, `translateY` starts to increase, hiding the header again.

TL;DR: I want the FlatList to grow when scrolling down, and shrink when scrolling up (to make more room for a header), but when I use the scroll offset to determine when to grow/shrink the list, the changing size of the list itself affects the scroll offset, leading to a circular dependency.

Any advice on how I can fix this or a different way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: did you solve it, because i have the same issue :(

Comment: @Kob_24 Yes, I did ultimately find a different way to solve it, more or less following the guide here: https://citymall.engineering/making-a-collapsible-sticky-header-animations-with-react-native-6ad7763875c3

Comment: TL;DR: The FlatList has a `paddingTop` in its `contentContainerStyle`, and the header is absolutely positioned on top of the list, so the FlatList itself is always filling the screen, removing the circular dependency.